# How to select random elements from list exclude some list?

Tags: c#, list, linq

So I have CardBase abstract class and 
I want to extract some random card elements exclude some specific card list. 
So I did like this.

```
public List<CardBase> GetRandExclude(List<CardBase> list, int elementsCount, List<CardBase> excludeList)
{        
    var returnCards = from card in list
                               where !excludeList.Contains(card)
                               select card;
    foreach (CardBase cd in returnCards.Take(elementsCount))
    {
        Debug.Log("Selected random card is "+cd.name);
    }
    return (List<CardBase>) returnCards.Take(elementsCount);
}
```

Did I do right? 
Are there better way?
Thanks in advance.

---

So I changed a little like this. And this seems works.

```
public List<CardBase> GetRandExclude(List<CardBase> list, int elementsCount, List<CardBase> excludeList)
{        
    var returnCards = from card in list
                               where !excludeList.Contains(card)
                               select card;
    foreach (CardBase cd in returnCards.OrderBy(arg => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(elementsCount).ToList())
    {
        Debug.Log("Selected random card is "+cd.name);
    }
    return returnCards.OrderBy(arg => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(elementsCount).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine you are getting some exceptions and/or unwanted results with your current approach. So please add some small example list to show all the aspects of your desired result.

Comment: I think if you want to make it random, you may want to consider using the [`System.Random class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) to generate a random number telling you how many numbers you should take out of the remaining list items and using the same class to generate the index of each number to pick from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the Linq route and use `Except` provided `CardBase` has some form of equality comparison. Other wise you could use the overload and provide a `IEqualityComparer<CardBase> comparer`

From there you want to randomly select cards from the available cards remaining.

```
static Random randomizer = new Random();
public List<CardBase> GetRandExclude(List<CardBase> list, int elementsCount, List<CardBase> excludeList) {
    var availableCards = list.Except(excludeList).ToList();
    int count = Math.Min(elementsCount, availableCards.Count);
    var selectedCards = new HashSet<CardBase>();
    do{
        var index = randomizer.Next(0, availableCards.Count);
        var card = availableCards[index];
        selectedCards.Add(card);
    } while (selectedCards.Count < count);
    foreach (CardBase cd in selectedCards) {
        Debug.Log("Selected random card is " + cd.name);
    }
    return selectedCards.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so there was simplest keyword, Except. And I am using Unity game engine now, so there unity provided Random.Range function. Then maybe I Don't need to use system.random()?

Comment: I am not familiar with Unity so I cannot say. There was no indication in your question that this pertained to unity

Comment: Looks like it allows duplicate selection of the same card... did I overlook something?

Answer (score 0):

You will get a casting exception with your code.

So first get the `IEnumerable` of cardBase.

Then return the list using `ToList()`

```
 public List<CardBase> GetRandExclude(List<CardBase> list, int elementsCount, List<CardBase> excludeList)
        {
            var returnCards = from card in list
                              where !excludeList.Contains(card)
                              select card;
            foreach (CardBase cd in returnCards.Take(elementsCount))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Selected random card is " + cd.name);
            }
            IEnumerable<CardBase> newList = returnCards.Take(elementsCount);
            return newList.ToList();
        }
```